# Writing Python Selenium test results to a file

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on generating a report for a suite of test cases written in Python using Selenium WebDriver. I'm kicking the test cases off with a main script, and I want to write the results to a .txt file that will eventually be sent out in an email.

When a test successfully runs, I get something like this in the terminal:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 15.566s

OK
```

This ^^^ is what I want to write to a file. I've tried

```
python test.py > file
```

to no avail. I've also tried

```
 sys.stdout = open('Results.txt', 'w')
```

which hasn't worked. I just want to write to a file that the test passed or failed, but it just won't print that part. I know it's something internal with the Selenium code, but I can't figure out where/what it is. Any other printing within the test will write to the file, but not the result.

Thanks for any advice!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tests results output is writen to `stderr`. Try

```
python test.py 2> file
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Now all I have to do is print the name of the test as well. If I throw in a normal "print" statement into the script it will only show up in the terminal, rather than the file. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3038369 You're wellcome! If you found answer serving your need, you might consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). For your question about print, you can catch both stdout and stderr in one go with `> file 2> &1` or print to stderr with `import sys; print >> sys.stderr, 'some text'`

Comment: Awesome. Answer accepted! You have no idea how long I've been trying to figure these things out!